# how to report a Ubuntu Touch bug

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Since yesterday I'm the proud owner of a Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition. As expected Ubuntu Touch isn't perfectly working jet, therefore I would like to report some bugs (from the phone if possible). Where and how should I submit bug reports for the OS or Unity 8 on the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of exiting bugs and a link to report new bugs on the [Avengers page of the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers).

However I am not sure what the most easy way is to report bugs directly from the phone.